# How to open a new terminal from my working terminal with same directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

Is there any command to open a new terminal from my working terminal with same directory while working with ssh in Linux?

e.g., I am working in the following terminal. My pwd is

```
/home/work/Kayan01/test_run
```

I want to open a new terminal directly from my working terminal, so that the pwd of the new terminal will be same as of my working terminal. i.e. the pwd of new terminal should also

```
/home/work/Kayan01/test_run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you connect to your remote server via

```
    ssh -x [host]
```

now run

```
    gnome-terminal &
```

this will open a terminal with the same ssh connection.

is this what your were after?